# How do I create dynamic legend in REST?

Tags: arcgis-10.1, arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript

I am going through [Generate renderer](http://help.arcgis.com/en/webapi/javascript/arcgis/jssamples/renderer_generate_renderer.html) sample in ArcGIS Java Script API and I want to make similar example using my rest service.

I am going through the [sample REST service](http://sampleserver6.arcgisonline.com/arcgis/rest/services/Census/MapServer) and wondering that how they created dynamic legend in REST?

I searched and tried to generate the dynamic legend at my end but its not displaying in REST. I am classifying data in Arc Map (using layer properties--symbology) and publishing on server but not getting dynamic legend..

So any help will be great !! thanks in advance : )

Software's : ArcGIS Server & Desktop 10.1 and JSAPI 3.2/3.3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need to use the Legend dijit. You can find documentation here:

http://help.arcgis.com/en/webapi/javascript/arcgis/jsapi/legend.html

You can see a working example here:

http://help.arcgis.com/en/webapi/javascript/arcgis/jssamples/widget_legendvisible.html